# Escrever arquivo txt em PHP

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o framework CakePHP, e preciso pegar o valor que o usuario entra no form e gravar este valor em um arquivo txt, porém ele esta me dando erro e não sei qual é o problema.

HTML:

```
<body class="bodyAddEstoque">
<h2 class="page-header">Editar Estoques</h2>
<?= $this->Form->create($produtos) ?>
<form action="/projeto/produtos/estoque/" method="post">
    <p>
        <label class="control-label">Configurar Estoque minimo: </label>
        <input type="number" name="estoque" step="any" class="form-control addDesconto inputEstoque" id="estoque"">
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="click">Editar</button>
</form>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Controller:

```
 public function configEstoque(){
        $this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['CategoriasProdutos', 'Fornecedores']
    ];
    $produtos = $this->paginate($this->Produtos);

    $this->set(compact('produtos'));

    //Salvando os produtos   
    if(isset($_POST['estoque'])){
        //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo.    
        $arquivo = fopen('configEstoque.txt','w');
        //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
        $conexao = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
        //Escreve no arquivo aberto.
        $texto = $_POST['estoque'];
        fwrite($conexao, $texto);    
        //Fecha o arquivo.
        fclose($conexao);
        $this->Flash->success(__('O produto foi editado com sucesso.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Porém esta me retornando estes erros: 
fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given 
Warning (2): fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
Warning (2): fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Por que você faz `fopen($arquivo)` se `$arquivo` já é um recurso definido por `fopen('configEstoque.txt')`?

Comment: Ah nao tinha me tocado, arrumei este detalhe, nao aparecem mais os erros, porém o arquivo txt permanece em branco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está correto, porém você deve passar o `PATH` do arquivo, você poder o server do PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Exemplo:

```
$local = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pasta/configEstoque.txt';
$arquivo = fopen($local,'w');
//Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
$conexao = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
//Escreve no arquivo aberto.
$texto = $_POST['estoque'];
fwrite($conexao, $texto);    
//Fecha o arquivo.
fclose($conexao);
```